# How to add a style sheet after all the other added style sheets in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, css

I created a child theme from a theme installed on my website. I created a custom page and added a style sheet to it using

`wp_enqueue_style( 'page-template', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-page-style.css')`

But it's added at the top of the other style sheets, which means that the style I add will be overridden by the other style sheets.

How can I make this style sheet at the end of the other style sheets, before the `</head>` so that it will override the other style sheets?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your function.php of your child theme

```
 example_enqueue_styles() {

// enqueue parent styles
wp_enqueue_style('parent-theme', get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css');

// enqueue child styles
wp_enqueue_style('child-theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ./css/custom-page-style.css', array('parent-theme'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'example_enqueue_styles');
```

Answer (score 0):

The full API of `wp_enqueue_style` is:

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

`$deps` stands for dependency, and by default it is an empty `array()`, you can pass in a list of dependencies that your `custom-page-style.css` required before it get injected to the html page.

For example:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-page-style.css', array('jQuery', 'bootstrap'));
```